# Undefined variable when using rgb2ind

Tags: matlab, image-processing, rgb

I have this simple program where I'm trying to set the number of colors of an image to 1000, but I get the following error: `Undefined function or variable 'rgb'.` I also tried with uppercase and quotes, although in the examples I found there where no quotes. I am using Matlab R2012a.

```
clc
clear all

rgbImage = imread('peppers.png');
[rgbImage,map]=rgb2ind(RGB,1000);
```

Comment: You can't use a variable which is never defined. First input parameter of `rgb2ind` is your image!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable you're using as the first parameter to `rgb2ind` is wrong.  You need to do:

```
[rgbImage, map] = rgb2ind(rgbImage, 1000);
```

My guess is that you consulted the MATLAB documentation on [`rgb2ind`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rgb2ind.html) and you literally took the first parameter to be substituted as `RGB`.  The documentation clearly says that `RGB` is an **image** loaded into MATLAB.  This is **not** a constant.

Comment: Oh. I missed the part where they named their image RGB. I must be really tired.

Comment: @TanatosDaniel - Ahaha no worries.  Yeah, there's an example there in the `doc` that shows you that `RGB` is a variable where an image was loaded in using `imread`.

Comment: Here http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rgb2ind.html they're starting the example before declaring the image. They are doing the declaration below, but I missed that. Only saw their third snippet.

Comment: @TanatosDaniel - Yeah I can see where you get confused.  The example loads in the image at the very first line though.  My guess is that they assume you have done this first part before proceeding to do `rgb2ind`.